# Insect wings bump texture

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

Hi fellas any idea how to "bump"-map the wings of this cockroach without using sculpting? Its bent stripes from the center of the object imo (but could be something else good looking). I tried to use the WAVE texture but with no luck. Have NO UV for now but if needed than I will do for sure.

In fact Im not good with procedural things in Node Editor.

Sincerely, Jan

Comment: You can unwrap the wing mesh and then either paint in Blender the ridges or save the texture and paint in another program. Then you can use this texture as the input of Bump map. Nodes can be daunting at first but after you have played with them for a bit they make sense

Comment: I know rob but in fact dunno how to manually paint the texture in ie Photoshop and be somehow "symetrical" along the way to look good.